# Make a file available during runtime in CMake and Qt Creator

Tags: c, cmake, qt-creator

I am trying to make a resource file available to the executable during the runtime. I am using the following CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(open-gl-test)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.c")

message(Executable is set!)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} glfw)

# List of files for which we add a copy rule.
set(data_SHADOW "basic.shader")

# We don't want to copy if we're building in the sourse dir.
if (NOT CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)
    message(WARNING "Directories are not equal")
    foreach(item IN LISTS data_SHADOW)
        message(STATUS ${item})
        add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/res/shaders/${item}"
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/res/shaders/${item}"
            DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/res/shaders/${item}"
        )
    endforeach()
else()
    message(WARNING "Directories are equal")
endif()

# Files are only copied if a target depends on them.
add_custom_target(data-target ALL DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/res/shaders/${data_SHADOW}")
```

And this is how I access the file.

```c
struct ShaderProgramSource source = parseShader("res/shaders/basic.shader");
```

But nothing gets copied to the project build directory and the even the messages don't show up in the ***compile output** window. And the error message I am getting is:

> Error while opening the file: No such file or directory

What might be the issue?

Comment: Why don't you use `file(COPY ...)`?

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I still don't understand why the other method is not working and why the messages are not being printed in Qt Creator.

Comment: "But nothing gets copied to the project build directory" - `add_custom_command` does not work until something depends on its OUTPUT. Your target `data-target` depends on the command's *input* (from the source directory), not output (from the binary directory).

Comment: Oh! I think I understands now. Thanks